# Add unaccepted questions back to the Unanswered Questions for users with high acceptance rate

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

Now that the Acceptance Rate is implemented for all users, I think it can be useful to put back some of the unaccepted questions in the Unanswered Questions group.

I'm saying this because some questions are not marked as answer simply because a suitable answer hasn't been found yet, at least from the question asker perspective, even if there are upvoted answers.

If an user has an high acceptance rate (>80%, for instance) then it is expected that he accepts all questions except the ones that he considers not to have a valid answer.

Therefore, for these users, the unaccepted questions should be considered unanswered.

I'm not entering in details about the rules, it's just to give an idea and ask for your opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Interesting idea.  It has merit, though I'd put the threshold closer to 90%.

However, I don't really really think it should be implemented.  The Unanswered Questions view is complicated enough already.  This would add a burden not only the site maintainers but also yet another conceptual burden to new users trying to understand the view.  We already have enough people come through here asking why this question or that shows as Unanswered, even though it has answers.

Comment: Note that Community Wiki questions often doesn't get an accepted answer, so they would skew the percentage.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it would complicate even more the Unanswered group. And Jeff wants to keep it simple :)

Comment: @Ivo community wiki questions are not counted towards the percetnage anyway, so won't skew any results

Answer (score 4):

Right now you could search for all the questions that haven't been marked with an accepted answer, which is pretty close to figuring it out as one that is "unanswered".

Just use the search modifier `hasaccepted:0`.

> [hasaccepted:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted:0)

When you're in the mood for only questions under a certain tag, drop a bag of that into the search as well:

> [hasaccepted:0 [jquery]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted:0+[jquery])